# rkt on windows server and .net Core

Tags: .net-core, rkt

I'm working on a .net core project in which I am going to use micro-service

can I use rkt to create and manage containers in windows server or rkt only works on Linux

modified :
I understood that the question was wrong

my question is :

I want to host several micro-service of .Net Core in rkt. Is it a normal task to do?

Comment: `micro-service` is an almost empty term. It means you want to create an HTTP service and *maybe* deploy it inside a container, maybe not. If you want to deploy on *Windows* without starting a VM, you'll have to use Windows Containers, preferably through Docker.

Comment: THX @panagiotis-kanavos  I cant use docker in my servers because of sanctions
what are the alternatives for docker to work on .net core project ?

Comment: I suspect you should understand what those terms mean in the first place and whether you *need* a container at all, or what it means to use a container. You *can't* use a Linux-only container engine on Windows, not unless you start a VM with that Linux distro, in which case you shouldn't care *what* the host OS is. Docker on Windows acts as a common command-line interface to Windows' own container engine. Even with containers though, the complexity *increases*. Using services doesn't mean using containers. You can deploy your service as a self-contained .NET Core standalone package

Comment: THX @panagiotis-kanavos - Our project are getting bigger and bigger, we need to do something about the complexity and slow development and changes within 6 month to one year.  We decided to use DevOps as culture. and .Net Core instead of .Net Framework also we need to use micro-service to separate the user-stories in server side to code and develop easier and more robust (I know the pros and cons),

Comment: last comment continues here : 
I understood that to implement the concept of micro-service I need to use docker to create and manage containers , but I cant use docker because of sanctions in my countries' servers (with proxies this problem may be solved but risky) . my question is "am I understanding my problem/solution correctly or I am missing something? " and what are the solutios for me ?

the last solution I could think of ws to use an alternative for docker which was rkt or lxc but I learnt that they work only on linux

Comment: I want to host several micro-service of .Net Core in rkt. Is it a normal task to do?

Answer (score 0):

I understood my question was basically wrong but I guess the problem is solved.

The solution for my problem is to use docker along with registry docker (docker-hub) which both are open-source. this solves my sanctions limitation problem now I can use docker . I will try it and let you know what I did.

thx everbody